# Beginner trying to resolve transistor issues

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

I have designed a basic transistor circuit with the EveryCircuit simulator.

The idea is that when the switch is open, one LED comes on and when the switch is closed the other LED lights up instead.

It appeared to work fine on the simulator, so I built it on a bread board.

I used an old BFY51 transistor from an old box of bits I have.

It worked great, just as I had intended.

Then I thought I would replace the BFY51 with a more up to date 2N2222., first making sure the B,E & C pins were in the correct slots.

I tested the circuit. Now, with the switch open it still works as it should, but with the switch closed, both LEDS light up rather than just the second one.

I know different transistors can have different operating parameters, but I could really do with some help to make my circuit work as intended with the 2N2222.

[image: Switch Open]

[image: Switch closed]

Comment: Peculiar circuit. A general pro tip is to always draw ground (or negative voltages) pointing down and positive pointing up for readability and plus points among EEs. Are you sure the 2222 is working and that you have the pins correctly?

Comment: I would suggest another clever trick to you - the transistor can connect a red LED (with lower forward voltage) in parallel to a green LED with higher forward voltage. You can artificially increase the LED forward voltage by connecting an ordinary Si diode in series. See also [my CD question & answer](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/278546#answer-279967) and [this paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279016).

Comment: Thanks for the tips.I actually just rotated the image of the circuit on its side as i posted it because it seemed like a good idea!! Pins are correct, but ill get a brand new one out of the packet and try that. I had convinced myself that it was a voltage / current issue rather than a dodgy component.

Comment: Thank you Circuit fantasist ill work through your suggestions as well :)

Comment: There is at least one variant of the 2n2222 that has E and C swapped.  Might check to be sure.  That would explain the symptoms

Comment: It was a dodgy transistor. Brand new one works fine. Thanks to everybody who replied :)